# RelativeLayout items not relative

Tags: android

I'm going to switch this to use a Table instead of a ListView, but my concern is that these items are not relative as they should be given the provided XML.

Is there something about the RelativeLayout being inside of Linear that's causing an issue?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ViewSwitcher
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dashboardViewSwitcher" android:layout_gravity="center">
        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <include
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    layout="@layout/loading" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/dashboardActivity_Header"
                    android:id="@+id/dashboardActivityHeader"/>
            <ListView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/dashboardActivityList"/>

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:text="@string/dashboardNews_Header"
                      android:id="@+id/dasboardNewsHeader"/>
            <ListView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/dashboardNewsList"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ViewSwitcher>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should declare what the components are **relative to** in the layout using `android:layout_below`, `android:layout_toLeftOf`, etc.

For example:

```
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/dashboardActivity_Header"
                android:id="@+id/dashboardActivityHeader"/>
        <ListView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/dashboardActivityHeader"
                android:id="@+id/dashboardActivityList"/>

       </RelativeLayout>
```